# Continous integration with .Net and Mono, Linux and Windows

Tags: .net, mono, continuous-integration

Consider the following:

- Code is C#.
- Code will compile and run on .Net and Mono.
- Some developers use Windows, and some Linux.
- Commits should be verified by a CI on both platforms (Windows/Linux) and {checkout, build, NUnit}.
- When a commit fails a mail should be sent.

It is preferable if there is a way for developers to see the current status of both platform builds at all time (such as CCTray). This regards both developers on Windows and Linux.

I have tried CruiseControl.net on Linux and Mono although they do not have official support. The console version of the server seems to be running okay after some modifications, although I couldn't get the web interface running. The CCTray fails miserably.

Could you recommend me some tool(s) that would live up to the points mentioned above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[TeamCity supports Mono officially](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/supported_platforms.html) and is pretty cool to boot!  Plus, it meets all the needs that you outlined above.

**edit**: and if you really like CCTray, you can [use it with TeamCity (with some work)](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/using-cctray-with-jetbrains-teamcity/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will look into it and post my findings :)

Comment: Sorry, I ended up leaving the company and didn't follow up on this. Good luck anyway!